# Angularjs - why can be injected Factory, but not Value?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, factory, inject

Why angular is giving `Error: [$injector:unpr]` error when injecting **value**, but not **factory**?

I'm injecting them by following:

```
$injector.get('informationStrings');
```

This works:

```
app.factory('informationStrings', function() {
    return {
        title: 'The 3nd step registration'
    }
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
app.value('informationStrings', {
    title: 'The 3nd step registration'
});
```

Comment: It should work, value is just another service recipe. Do you have a demo to show the issue?

Comment: I have big application, the actual code is really huge, just when I dig I found that issue, don't know why.

Comment: Try to break down yourself and find out if you can replicate it with a minimal example. Issue would be elsewhere in your code. One more thing is you wont be able to get factory or value(except for provider and constant) in the config block though.

Answer (score 0):

I try to find what are your problem. But I suspect it's a small misspelling.

Could you try to compare your code with my sample on http://goo.gl/SM38JE (please look for the Newfile.js) ?